# how to make a function which tells if two lists are equivalent in python

Tags: python, function, equivalence

This question will be really annoying due to the fact it is for a class and we have a lot of restrictions on our code.

The objective is to make a function to see if two lists (random ordered) have the same elements in them. So, if `a=[2,5,4]` and `b=[4,2,5]` `a==b` would be `true`. Now the restrictions are that we cannot use any built-in functions except `len()`. So I can't use anything like `set()` or the like. I also am not allowed to edit the lists, so I could not check to see if items are in both lists then delete them as I go if they are in both lists until it is empty.

With all these restrictions, I'm running out of ideas. Please help.

Comment: Please read: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries This should give you an idea of what to do. Another way is to use: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: Can you use the `in` operator?

Comment: Please, show us more precise testcases... E.g. what about `are_items_equal([2,2,5,4], [2, 5, 4])`? Should return True or False? Is `are_items_equal(a, b) == are_items_equal(b, a)` is always True? etc...

Comment: The tricky part will be telling `[2, 2, 5, 4]` and `[4, 5, 2, 5]` apart.

Comment: You could always sort them yourself and the go down the line `ForAll i Where a[i] == b[i] (True)`

Comment: Sorting or using a dict/counter is the best idea. After the sort, you can simply use the `==` operator between the two lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is recursivity allowed ? That way, you don't have to modify existing lists in place. Obviously, not very efficient, but given your requirements this shouldn't really be an issue here...

```
def are_items_equal(a, b):
    # First the guard clause: if the first list is empty,
    # return True if the second list is empty too, False otherwise
    if not a:
        return not b

    # There is now at least 1 item in list a
    # Perform a linear search in the b list to find a[0]
    # (could have used a "for" loop, but I assumed here this was
    # forbidden too)
    ib = 0;
    while ib < len(b):
        if a[0] == b[ib]:
            # At this point, we know that at index `ib` in list `b`
            # there is the same item as in `a[0]`
            # Both list match if the "rest" of those two lists match too
            # Check that by performing a recursive call to are_items_equal
            # (discarding the pair matched at this step)
            return are_items_equal(a[1:], b[:ib]+b[ib+1:])
        ib += 1

    # You only reach this point when `a[0]` was not found
    # in the `b` list.
    return False
```

Testing:

```
test_case = (
    ([2,5,4], [4,2,5]),
    ([2, 2, 5, 4], [4, 5, 2, 5]),
    ([2,2,5,4], [4,2,5]),
    ([2,2,5,4],[4,2,5,2]),
)

for a,b in test_case:
    print(are_items_equal(a, b), a, b)
```

Producing:

```
True [2, 5, 4] [4, 2, 5]
False [2, 2, 5, 4] [4, 5, 2, 5]
False [2, 2, 5, 4] [4, 2, 5]
True [2, 2, 5, 4] [4, 2, 5, 2]
```

Comment: that worked excellently, and i think i semi understand how your code is working but could you explain it a little bit more to me, just so i get a clear understanding of how it works and i can implement it or parts in other areas of coding

Comment: @Travis Glad to have helped you. I add some comments to the code. Let me know if something is still not clear.

Comment: thankyou that helped a lot. i didn't think about using recursive function. our teacher hasn't said anything specific against it so i just won't bring it up and he can't hold it against me. now to rearrange my sort function which he didn't like... despite it being 3x more efficient than his demo haha. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the best solution is to use [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set), but you are restricted. Here is one way to do it without any "built-in functions":

```
def equal_lists(l1, l2):
    for i in l1:
        if not i in l2:
            return False
    for i in l2:
        if not i in l1:
            return False
    return True
```

**EDIT**
If you want to "account for two lists with all the same elements but different numbers of each":

```
def occur(it):
    d = {}
    for i in it:
        try:
            d[i] += 1
        except KeyError:
            d[i] = 1
    return d

occur(a) == occur(b)
```

Comment: close but your code doesn't account for two lists with all the same elements but different numbers of each

Comment: You did not specify the desired behavior for that case in your question; please be more specific next time.